# Handling duplicate pages in graph API using existing FB de-duplication

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, duplicates

Edit: I'm working on an application that stores a user's education history and groups users by the school they attend. Having two representations of the same school is unacceptable. In the example below, I outline a particular case (one of many) that has confounded me.

Clearly Facebook has a mechanism to detect duplicate pages, and I am looking for any solution that would take advantage of this existing functionality.

---

The graph API represents these two pages with different IDs, but on the front end they redirect to a single page. Take a look:

- [graph.facebook.com/108727889151725](http://graph.facebook.com/108727889151725)
- [graph.facebook.com/110886578949219](http://graph.facebook.com/110886578949219)

Notice one has ~21,000 likes and the other has 250. If we type those page IDs into a browser, watch what happens:

- [facebook.com/108727889151725](http://facebook.com/108727889151725)
- [facebook.com/110886578949219](http://facebook.com/110886578949219)

Respectively, those redirect to:

- [facebook.com/georgewashingtonuniversity?rf=108727889151725](https://www.facebook.com/georgewashingtonuniversity?rf=108727889151725)
- [facebook.com/georgewashingtonuniversity?rf=110886578949219&highlight_redirect=yes](https://www.facebook.com/georgewashingtonuniversity?rf=110886578949219&highlight_redirect=yes)

Which, as you may notice, are the same page! So here's my question:

**Is there any way I can use Facebook's de-duplication in my app?**